# To set Asp Radio button attribute (value) to a string

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

In the below mentioned code iam adding the attribute 'value' to the radio button. I need to know how to set the radio button 'value' attribute to a string.

Thanks in advance.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton rdoAuthModeSingleFactor = new RadioButton();
    rdoAuthModeSingleFactor.Text = authModeObj["AuthenticationModes"].ToString();
    string authModeIdVal = authModeObj["AuthenticationModeId"].ToString();
    rdoAuthModeSingleFactor.GroupName = "AuthModes";
    rdoAuthModeSingleFactor.ID = "AuthModeRdoID";
    rdoAuthModeSingleFactor.Attributes.Add("Value", authModeIdVal);
    plhldrAuthModes1.Controls.Add(rdoAuthModeSingleFactor);
}

protected void btnAuthModeSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    //Here iam using placeholder functionalities
    // radio button object name is rdo
            string authenticationModeCheckedVal = rdo.Text;  // how to get value of radio button instead of text
    }
```

Comment: are you working on `web forms` or `win forms`.

Comment: working for web forms

Comment: then you have to use `RadioButtonList`, because in `RadioButton` there is a property for `Text` but not for `Value`.

Comment: @Rahul yes you are right, but iam using attribute for radio buton, so how to get that attribute value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string strResult = rdotest.Attributes["Value"];
```

Answer (score 4):

**For Web Forms :**

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdogender" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Male">Male</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Female">Female</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

And CS-in some button click

```
string value=rdogender.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
```

Hope you understand and works for you.

Answer (score 0):

try  **rdo.SelectedValue** instead of  **rdo.Text**

Comment: I can't see selected property for radio button in intellisense

Comment: `radiobutton` has no `SelectedValue` property but `RadioButtonList` have.